# Когда правильно закрывать файл и снимать блокировку?

Tags: php

Приветствую. Мне нужно сделать следующее:

1. Прочитать содержимое файла.
2. Удалить файл.

При этом файл не должен быть доступен для записи до тех пор, пока мы не закончим чтение и не удалим файл.

Вот фрагмент кода:

```
$h = fopen(__DIR__.'/file.txt', 'r+');
flock($h, LOCK_EX);
$str = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/file.txt');
unlink(__DIR__.'/test.txt');
flock($h, LOCK_UN);
fclose($h);
```

Правильно ли так писать? Просто закрывать и разблокировать файл, которого уже нет выглядит не очень корректно... А если удалять уже после разблокировки и вызова `fclose()`, то в промежутке между `fclose()` и `unlink()` другой скрипт ведь может что-то записать в файл.

Comment: А зачем вам удалять файл? Вырежете из него информацию и закройте.

Comment: @ArchDemon, да, можно в принципе. Мне просто нужно открывать этот файл только если другой скрипт записал в него информацию. Я перед открытием проверяю на `file_exists()`. Но в вашем варианте можно использовать и `filesize() == 0`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Просто закрывать и разблокировать файл, которого уже нет

А он ещё есть в действительности. И будет доступен его открывшим приложениям всё время, пока на него есть открытые ссылки. И только когда закроется последний открытый дескриптор файл пропадёт (и то пропадёт только когда ФС скомандует trim либо переиспользует блоки под что-нибудь другое).

```
melkij@melkij:~$ echo 42 > tmp/rmfile
melkij@melkij:~$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > $fp = fopen('tmp/rmfile', 'r+');
php > unlink('tmp/rmfile');
php > echo fread($fp, 100);
42
php > var_dump(file_exists('tmp/rmfile'));
bool(false)
```

Эта особенность, кстати, иногда может помочь [восстановить случайно удалённый файл](https://superuser.com/a/693051) чтением открытого дескриптора из `/proc/$PID/fd`

Comment: Благодарю, тогда оставляю так, как у меня и было.

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще из книги PHP5 2-е издание (Котерова):

```
<?
# Модель циклического процесса с исключительной блокировкой

$file = "file.txt";

// Создаем пустой файл, если его еще нет
// Если файл существует, это его не разрушит
fclose(fopen($file,"a+b"));

// Блокируем файл
$f = fopen($file,"r+b") or die ("Error");

while(true)
{
        flock($f,LOCK_EX); // Ждем пока мы не станем единственными

        // В этой точке можем быть уверены, что только эта программа работает с файлом

        fflush($f);         // Сбрасываем буферы на диск
        flock($f, LOCK_UN); // Освобождаем файл

        // Например засыпаем на 10 секунд
        sleep(10);
}

fclose($f);    


// или


# Модель процесса читателя

$file = "file.txt";

// Создаем пустой файл, если его еще нет
// Если файл существует, это его не разрушит
fclose(fopen($file,"a+b"));

// Блокируем файл
$f = fopen($file,"r+b") or die ("Error");
flock($f,LOCK_SH); // Ждем пока не завершится процесс-писатель
// В этой точке может быть уверены, что в файл никто не производит запись
// Все сделано снимаем блокировку
fclose($f);
```

Comment: А оно точно работает? Как оно выйдет из while(true)?

Comment: для примера приведен